# java add to array after initialize

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Loop {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        String array[] = {"chocoalte", "cheese"};
        System.out.println(array[0]);
        array[2] = "coco";
    }
}
```

Why will this not work? eclipse gives me a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` I'm assuming that I cannot do this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, arrays are a fixes size in Java. I would recommend using a `List` instead:

```
public class Loop {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       List<String> food = new ArrayList<String>();
       food.add("chocolate");
       food.add("cheese");
       food.add("coco");
       food.add("French Fries");
    }
 }
```

The `ArrayList` class is backed by an array, and the class is smart enough to create a new list and copy all of the elements into it when it needs to grow. You could implement this yourself, or you could take advantage of well tested and understood code and use one of the library classes (either [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), depending on your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays are of fixed size. [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), on the other hand, can be appended to.